# Is there an API to enable the Nexus 6 "Ambient Display"?

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to build a Daydream app that used the Nexus 6's [Ambient Display](http://www.androidauthority.com/ambient-display-lollipop-541198/).  Is there an API and if so where is the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by calling:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DOZE_ENABLED, on ? 1 : 0);
```

Unfortunately, writing vale to Secure setting is not allowed on a non-root device.

Reference: AndroidSource6.0.1r30\packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\DisplaySettings.java

Comment: Does this just enable/disable Ambient Display, or is this for Doze? Doze is different than the Ambient Display feature. If I only want to turn on/off Ambient Display (notifications showing up when I wave my hand over my phone or lift it) will this work?