# How can I turn Ambient Display on/off programmatically?

Tags: android, root, android-doze, android-doze-and-standby

I want to turn ambient display on and off from an app I am creating.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825436/is-there-an-api-to-enable-the-nexus-6-ambient-display) where someone was asking something similar. The accepted answer was this line of code:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DOZE_ENABLED, on ? 1 : 0);
```

But I'm wondering if this is just for Ambient Display, or the whole "Doze" feature? Also, the question was referring to a Nexus 6, but will this work for any Marshmallow+ phone with the Ambient Display option?

Thanks!